# Copy and paste an excel chart into word without linking or saving as a GIF

Tags: excel, excel-2010, copy-paste, vba

I am a total VBA novice, but I've managed to cobble together some code which allows me to export an excel 2010 chart into a new Word 2010 document.  The only problem I have is that I would like to unlink the chart from excel once it is exported, so that it doesn't change when excel is updated.  I've looked everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

The only other code which seems to fit the bill takes the chart and saves it as an image prior to pasting it, but this would not work as I have nowhere to save the image - users in our organisation do not have access to the C:\ drive, and without knowing everyone's user details, I cannot write code which will do the job.

The code I've written so far is this, which does work, but does not unlink:

```
 Sub Copy_Paste_Report_1_Graph_to_new_word_document()
'
'Copy/Paste An Excel Chart Into a New Word Document
'(VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)

'Excel Objects
Dim ChartObj As ChartObject

'Word Objects
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False



'Copy Chart from Excel
  Set ChartObj = Worksheets("External Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 1")

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

'Copy Excel Chart
  ChartObj.Copy

'Paste Chart into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False _

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I've probably included more than I need to, but like I said, I'm a novice.

Comment: Why not to try `ChartObj.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture` and `myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial`?

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you! worked great.

Comment: Posted the solution as answer, please click to accept it, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.CopyPicture` and `.PasteSpecial` methods:

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Report_1_Graph_to_new_word_document()

    Dim ChartObj As ChartObject
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document

    Set ChartObj = Worksheets("External Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    ChartObj.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```